# mmap return value during error

Tags: c, mmap

I could see in the mmap man page the return value during error condition is `(void *)-1.`

how c compiler will treat `(void *)` before a constant, here `-1`.

is the following code snippet is the correct way of checking the error value of mmap?

```
int *p;
p = (int *)mmap();
if(p == -1)
        printf("error \n");
```

do we need to use the following error condition check.

```
if(*p == -1)
        printf("error \n");
```

Comment: You should use `MAP_FAILED`, rather than `-1` (or `(void *)-1`).

Answer (score 6):

```
int *p = NULL;
void *ret = mmap();
if(ret == MAP_FAILED) {  /* Or if(ret == (void *)-1) */
  /* error */
} else {
  p = ret;
}
```

Check literally with `(void *)-1` or use `MAP_FAILED` macro which is defined to `(void *)-1`.

`if(*p == -1)` is incorrect as you can not dereference the pointer unless you ensure the validity of the pointer. Otherwise the behaviour of the program is undefined.

Comment: We can use void * before a constant ? is it valid in all scenarios.

Comment: For `-1` it is fine. For any generic integer use `(void *) (intptr_t) integer_constant`

Comment: can you please give a sample line of code for "(void *) (intptr_t) integer_constant"

Comment: `int i = 42;void *p = (void *)(intptr_t)i;`

Comment: "intptr_t" means "int *"

Comment: No an integer with size of pointer. Read more about this in C text book.